# How do I delete multiple releases on TestPyPI?

Tags: pypi

I do see how to delete *one* release, but there are many old ones.

I am looking for a "mark many and delete"...

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Have you tried [checking the site FAQ](https://pypi.org/help/), looking through the [issue tracker](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues), or [asking on Twitter](https://twitter.com/PyPI)? Stack Overflow is not tech support for a third-party website. As a refresher, please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could delete each one manually. I dont think there is a function for deleting separately.